# Booting application from rc.local in rhel6.4

Tags: linux

I am using RHEL6.4 . I want run my newt based application from `rc.local` so that it runs as the only one application . But it's not working.

How  can I run this application to run before login to system  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in the file `rc.local` :

```
/root/bin/start_bb
```

Or if its a service then :

```
#service oracle start
```

If you want to run a script then follow this :

```
/home/user/script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run an application with graphical interface you can't do this with rc.local or runlevel. If you want to run an application with graphical interface you need to use something else (I use lxsession personally).